# Using a composer package

Tags: php, steam

I have not used PHP before and would need help, as I need to use a specific PHP [package](https://github.com/Allyans3/steam-market-api-v2) for my project. I have downloaded the package with Composer, but I am not entirely sure how to use it in my PHP script.
This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use allyans3/steam-market-api-v2
    $api = new SteamApi();
    $options = [
        'market_hash_name' => "AK-47 | The Empress (Field-Tested)",
    ];
    
    $response = $api->getSaleHistory(730, $options);

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I refresh my localhost web server it does not seem to work.

Could you please tell me how to do this properly?

Comment: What does not work? Do you get any errors? What does the $response variable contain?

Comment: just try `echo $response` and see result or `var_dump($response)`

Comment: The most current I get is: 'GET /www/site.php - Uncaught Error: Class "SteamApi" not found in C:\Users\XXX\XXX\site.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\XXX\XXX\site.php on line 13. 'But I don't know how to access this class.

Comment: Your `use` statement is incorrect. The SteamApi class is in [the `SteamApi` namespace](https://github.com/Allyans3/steam-market-api-v2/blob/master/src/SteamApi.php), so it needs to be imported with `use \SteamApi\SteamApi;`.